# How to create Parametric slicer in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi-desktop

I would like to add a slicer/filter which has to pass as a parameter to stored procedure/View and get the data from the DataBase. Know how to pass a parameter from Power BI to SQL Server, but don't know how to add the parameter as a slicer[image: Screenshot]

Comment: This is not possible with Power BI, you will have to load the dataset, then the slicer filters it. You can't do the call to the SP dynamically. Do you need to use an SP? or can you use a table or view and use direct query?

Comment: Need to use SP,